# Firebase auth/argument-error when building NextJS through github actions

Tags: firebase, next.js, github-actions

I'm building a NextJS website which functions with the static HTML export. I have setup a github action which builds and exports the project with yarn. This action works perfectly locally, however on Github I get the following error:

```
  Error [FirebaseError]: Firebase: Error (auth/argument-error).
  {
      type: 'FirebaseError',
      code: 'auth/argument-error',
      customData: { appName: '[DEFAULT]' }
  }
```

I debugged the entire Firebase connection I have written but everything seems according to the Firebase docs. What is happening?

Comment: Please show the logs and the YAML.